# response.sendError(403), but return is 404

Tags: java, http, web, filter, response

the code like this:

```
void doFilter(request, response, chain){
  try{
    //something code process
    validate(request);
    chain.doFilter(request,response);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    response.sendError(403,"Forbidden");
  }

}
void validate(request) throws Exception{
   //validate params,if not validate,just throw exception.
}
```

directly visit the web project, not pass nginx and something like that.
but the status return is always 404, is here someone who can help me? thanks a lot.
By the way, I got the right status when i run the project on my windows PC, but not worked when it is on linux .

Comment: It's not returned by your code. The request is not handled (so 404 is returned not found). Probably the mapping is wrong or the URL or another mistake

Comment: I'm sure the request is enter this filter and run the code, but when throws a exception, it seems not worked using sendError() method. ps: i just updated the code above.

Comment: Do you have another handler that redirects the user somewhere on error? For example if 403 is returned you might redirect to some "error page" which is not found?

Answer (score 0):

The response code of [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) means *not found*. You attempt to send a request to a URL, but it is not found by the server, so your code will not run, hence **404** instead of **403**. You need to check the settings for the URLs and find out why your URL is not matched. Could be a rewrite rule. When you resolve that, your code will run and will try to execute `chain.doFilter`. If not successful, it will return **403**.

Comment: I'm sure the request is enter this filter and run the code, but when throws a exception, it seems not worked using sendError() method.

Comment: @user3548664 did you try this with a debugger? Did it enter your code?

Comment: yes, It's surely entered this filter code. i tried to do validation with params, when it's not validated , it throws a exception to run sendError() method.

Comment: @user3548664 that probably means that you are sending a request on sendError and the target of that request is not found.

Comment: @ Lajos Arpad , i used request to get the params for validation, so can not found the request seems not to be the reason. And i got the right status on my windows PC, but failed to get the right status on Linux. It's really a strange point.

Comment: @user3548664 the root path might be changed and the relative location you try to reach might be invalid.